# Memory size not the same as in partition?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, ram

I have installed an Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS and everything worked fine, except one little thing.

The memory size is not the same as the Linux filesystem.

I have partitioned it this way:

- output of `lsblk`:

  ```
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  sda      8:0    0  7.5G  0 disk
  ├─sda1   8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
  ├─sda2   8:2    0  6.5G  0 part /
  └─sda3   8:3    0  452M  0 part [SWAP]
  ```
- output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8012390400 bytes, 15649200 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: gpt

  Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
  /dev/sda1      2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
  /dev/sda2   1050624 14723071 13672448  6.5G Linux filesystem
  /dev/sda3  14723072 15648767   925696  452M Linux swap
  ```

From the outputs of both commands, it can be seen that the size of the sda2 partition is **6.5 GB**.

- But when i check the meminfo file with `cat /proc/meminfo` I get this output:

  ```
  MemTotal:        3865612 kB
  MemFree:         3505612 kB
  MemAvailable:    3548680 kB
  ```

  This means only **3.8 GB** are shown as total memory size and not 6.5 GB. Why is that so?
- The wrong memory size is also shown in the `htop` command:

  ```
  1  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||82.2%]  Tasks: 32,17 thr; 2 running
  2  [                          0.0%]  Load average: 0.73 0.80 0.82
  Mem[||||               93.3M/3.69G]  Uptime: 01:15:50
  Swp[                       0K/452M]
  ```

  Here it can also be seen, that the size is **~3.7 GB** and not 6.5 GB. But the SWAP size is correct.

Why is the memory size 3.9 GB and not 6.5 GB? Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: disk storage is not memory

Comment: Oh so I have mixed up the definitions? Does that mean everything is alright? Do I have 6.5 GB disk storage?

Comment: yes, 6.5GB disk storage capacity on sda2, and 3.7GB RAM memory

Comment: @ravery Thanks, I got a bit confused with the terminology, now is everything fine :) If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it, if you don't, I will write an own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk storage capacity and memory are two different things; although, they are measured with the same unit.

Your partition size (6.5GB) measures how much data can be stored on your drive.

Memory is how much RAM you have installed + any virtual memory (swap space) that may be in use. In your case, you have 3.7GB RAM and ~0.4GB Swap